# How to notate a set of point meeting a given condition?

Tags: notation

How do you formulate *the set of the n closest neighbours within the radius r of point P* with proper mathematical syntax?

Comment: And what if there are several points the same distance away from $P$, so that none of them are "closest"?

Comment: Assuming $X$ being is set of all points, you could go for something like this: $$
S = \arg\max \{\lvert S^\prime\rvert \mid S^\prime\subseteq X\cap \mathcal{B}(P,r), \lvert S^\prime\rvert \leq n\}
$$
If the set you are trying to get is well-defined, this would work; if there are no such set (too many points at equal distance from $P$, or not enough in the open ball of radius $r$), then $S$ will be either empty or will contain less than $n$ points.

Comment: @ClementC. Is $\arg\max $  understood as empty set when the maximum is not unique? I though it would be the set of maxima, i.e., sets of sets in this case. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) also thinks so.

Comment: Yes, that would be an issue indeed if there are several sets achieving this maximum. I don't know how to formalize it, though, without the assumption (implicit in the OP's question) that there is only one such set...

Answer (score 1):

There is no notation that will do the job for you;  you have to explain the concept to the reader first. When doing so, you'll have to address corner cases:

- some points have equal distance to $P$, so there is no unique set of "closest $n$"
- The number of points within radius $r$ of $P$ is less than $n$.

Once you decided how to treat these cases, and communicated your decision to the reader *in words*, you can give the set any notation you want, such as $\mathcal N_{n,r}(p)$.